# Proving subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if the following is a set subspace for $P_n$ for an appropriate value n.

1. $p(t) = a + t^2$, where $a$ is in $\mathbb{R}$
2. All polynomials in $P_n$ such that $p(0) = 0$

Now I know that to prove it, we would need to show that

1. the $0$ would in the $P_n$ would have to be in it
2. it would have to be closed from addition
3. scalar multiples would have to be closed

Can someone show me how to do this? I still don't quite understand.
For 1, I know that $p(0) = a$, but how do we know a does not equal 0?
How do we prove 2 and 3 for 1?

I don't quite understand the part where you are to take to vectors like $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ and show that $p(x)+p(y) = p(x+y)$ to prove the second part.

For 2, I guess $p(0) = 0$ already proves the first part, but how do you prove 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can considerably reduce the amount of work you have to do by using the [one-step subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test).

For example, to prove that the collection $V$ of all polynomials $p$ in $P_n$ such that $p(0)=0$ is a subspace, let $p,q\in V$ and let $\lambda\in \Bbb R$. Then
$$
(p+\lambda\cdot q)(0)=p(0)+(\lambda\cdot q)(0)=p(0)+\lambda\cdot q(0)=0+\lambda\cdot 0=0
$$
so that $p+\lambda\cdot q\in V$. Hence $V$ is a subspace of $P_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Pick two typical polynomials that satisfy 1. and see if the sum also satisfies 1. or not? Also if check $\lambda f$ satisfies 1. for $f$ satisfying 1. and $\lambda\in \mathbb C$. Do the same for 2.